# Quick question: SES of refexive sheaves on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Things are algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$ (or maybe even complex analytic.)

Suppose we have a short exact sequence of torsion free coherent sheaves on a surface $X$ (normal maybe?):

$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0.$

Does it induce:

$0\rightarrow A^{\vee\vee}\rightarrow B^{\vee\vee}\rightarrow C^{\vee\vee}\rightarrow 0?$

Comment: Not in general. Try the resolution of the ideal sheaf of a point in the projective plane, unless you meant the latter to be just a complex, not necessarily exact.

Comment: If A, B and C are reflexive, as suggested by your title, your second diagram is isomorphic to the first one.

Comment: Oh no. I do mean non-reflexive (=non locally free in this case) A, B and C.